# PhoneGap Build error "plugin unsupported: org.apache.cordova.core.camera"

Tags: cordova

I am getting an error: "plugin unsupported: org.apache.cordova.core.camera.", when uploading a project to PhoneGap Build.

Also have this error: "This app uses plugins from the PhoneGap Build repository. These plugins won't be accessible after Nov 15th, 2016".

Comment: try this instead ?
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `confing.xml` change

```
org.apache.cordova.core.camera
```

to

```
org.apache.cordova.camera
```

[**read more here**](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, too easy!

Had this in config.xml:
`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.camera" />`

Needed this:
`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" source="npm" />`

I also had this error: "plugin unsupported: com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar." and had this in config.xml:
`<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />`

But needed this:
`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" source="npm" />`

It follows that this should work for other plugins - just search for it on Google / NPM and paste in the URL. Or perchance the plugin isn't even used in the app and can be removed...

I also tried this at some point: 
`<gap:plugin spec="https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin.git" source="npm" />`

Then I ran into: "Error - One of your plugins required the gradle android build tool to build - You can fix this here".

And changed:
`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />`

To:
`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.4.0" />`

Then ran into "Some official plugins have to be updated if using PhoneGap >= 4.0.0. Please upgrade the version of any plugins that may include the following file: CordovaUri.java - You can fix this here".

And updated the plugins back to named plugins as found in NPM.